# ActionBarSherlock Context menu change for each tab

Tags: android, actionbarsherlock

I have a `SherlockFragmentActivity` with 4 tabs in it. It holds `Fragment`s and everything works fine except I want to change the context menu when the user goes to a different tab.

My tabs are setup similarly (not exactly) as what is on this page:

http://www.javacodegeeks.com/2013/06/android-action-bar-with-tab.html

If each tab has its own context menu, how would that refresh be triggered from the listener?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found the answer to this in another post, just searched differently:

[Android: How to recreate Action bar when fragment changed](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14479749/android-how-to-recreate-action-bar-when-fragment-changed)

Calling this function from the activity:

```
invalidateOptionsMenu();
```