# Android - Separate ActionBar Option Menu's For Each TabHost Tab

Tags: android, boolean

I'm making a web browser, it has four tabs (tabs are done using tab host) and I need a separate options menu for each of the tabs.
How would I go about doing so? Using boolean?

Thank you!

**Edit** (How the tabs are done)

```
TabHost th = (TabHost) findViewById (R.id.tabHost);

    th.setup();
    TabSpec specs = th.newTabSpec("Tab1");
    specs.setContent(R.id.tab1);
    specs.setIndicator("Tab 1");
    th.setCurrentTab(1);
    th.addTab(specs);
```

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/8279981/how-can-i-change-action-bar-actions-dynamically

Comment: @Tim Thanks but I'm not using fragments. I'll edit how I did the tabs.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You could use a [`OnTabChangeListener`](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/widget/TabHost.html#setOnTabChangedListener%28android.widget.TabHost.OnTabChangeListener%29) to get a callback, when the user changed to another tab. Based on the tab ID, you can manipulate the options menu.

Call [`invalidateOptionsMenu()`](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/app/Activity.html#invalidateOptionsMenu%28%29) when you need to alter the menu. Then, [`onCreateOptionsMenu()`](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/app/Activity.html#onCreateOptionsMenu%28android.view.Menu%29) will be called. You can then inflate another `menu.xml`. Alternatively, you could also wait for the subsequent call to [`onPrepareOptionsMenu()`](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/app/Activity.html#onPrepareOptionsMenu%28android.view.Menu%29) and toggle the visibility of single menu items via [`setVisible()`](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/view/MenuItem.html#setVisible%28boolean%29).

**Example:** *(haven't tested it, but it should work more or less)*

```
private static final String TAB_1 = "tab1";
private static final String TAB_2 = "tab2";

private TabHost mTabHost;

private final TabHost.OnTabChangeListener onTabChangedListener = new TabHost.OnTabChangeListener {
    public void onTabChanged(String tabId){
        invalidateOptionsMenu();
    }
};

public void onCreate(Bundle b){
    TabHost mTabHost = (TabHost) findViewById (R.id.tabHost);
    // ...
    mTabHost.setOnTabChangedListener(onTabChangedListener);
    mTabHost.setCurrentTabByTag(TAB_1);
}

public boolean onCreateOptionsMenu(Menu menu){
    final String currentTab = mTabHost.getCurrentTabTag();

    if(TAB_1.equals(currentTab)){
        getMenuInflater().inflate(R.menu.main_tab1.xml, menu);
    } else if(TAB_2.equals(currentTab)){
        getMenuInflater().inflate(R.menu.main_tab2.xml, menu);
    }
}
```

Comment: Hello, thanks for helping! I'm a little confused, could you please give an example of the first method?

Comment: I added an example. Mind, that depending on your target API level, you need to include the support library. If so, the method calls would be `supportInvalidateOptionsMenu()` and `getSupportMenuInflater()`.