# Change actionbar menu in fragment

Tags: android, android-fragments

I want to load another menu xml when I load the fragment.I am using this code in main activity:

```
@Override
public boolean onCreateOptionsMenu(Menu menu) {
    getMenuInflater().inflate(R.menu.main, menu);
    return true;
}
```

I am using this code in fragment:

```
@Override
public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setHasOptionsMenu(true);
}
@Override
public void onCreateOptionsMenu(Menu menu,MenuInflater inflater) {
    getActivity().getMenuInflater().inflate(R.menu.fragment_menu, menu);
    super.onCreateOptionsMenu(menu, inflater);
}
```

When user loads the fragment,activity menu should remove then fragment menu should load to actionbar.
And when user clicks the back button from fragment,fragment menu should remove then main activity menu should load to action bar.

Now this code is not removing the old menu,it's adding new menu to near of old menu.

How can I do this ?

Comment: use invalidateOptionsMenu() for this...

Comment: Where should I put this ?

Answer (score 9, accepted):

You Can use **`menu.clear();`** method.

It remove all existing items from the menu, leaving it empty as if it had just been created.

Try this..

```
@Override
public void onCreateOptionsMenu(Menu menu,MenuInflater inflater) {
    menu.clear(); // clears all menu items..
    getActivity().getMenuInflater().inflate(R.menu.fragment_menu, menu);
    super.onCreateOptionsMenu(menu, inflater);
}
```

Comment: It's cleaning now but I have one more problem.When user clicks to back button from fragment I am running invalidateOptionsMenu() but still showing fragment menu.

Comment: if you want to remove old menu items.. its better to use menu.clear() method at first.. its easy and useful.

Comment: You got it wrong.I put the clear to oncreateoptionsmenu in activity.But when I try to back from fragment still showing fragment menu in actionbar.I think oncreateoptionsmenu is not running again when I press the back button.

Comment: try to put it in onPrepareOptionMenu()

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/8279981/how-can-i-change-action-bar-actions-dynamically

Answer (score 3):

You Should call **`setHasOptionsMenu(true);`** method in `onCreateView`.

It tells fragment got a menu.

Then Try below codes...

```
@Nullable
    @Override
    public View onCreateView(@NonNull LayoutInflater inflater, @Nullable ViewGroup container, @Nullable Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        setHasOptionsMenu(true);
        return inflater.inflate(R.layout.fragment_manage, container, false);
    }


@Override
public void onCreateOptionsMenu(Menu menu,MenuInflater inflater) {
    menu.clear(); // clears all menu items..
    inflater.inflate(R.menu.fragment_menu, menu);
    super.onCreateOptionsMenu(menu, inflater);
}
```

Answer (score 2):

Try this:

```
@Override
public void onCreateOptionsMenu(Menu menu, MenuInflater inflater) {
  inflater.inflate(R.menu.fragment_menu, menu);
  super.onCreateOptionsMenu(menu,inflater);
}
```

Hope it helps